# Right to left text in delphi trayicon BaloonHint

Tags: delphi, localization, right-to-left

Is there a way to align text right in the delphi trayicon BaloonHint?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use your own hint window

```
type
 TRTLHint = class(THintWindow)
 protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
 end;

procedure TRTLHint.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL;
end;
```

You can then use this TRTLHint in [this way](http://www.chami.com/tips/delphi/112996D.html).